# Is there a web-based equivalent of Microsoft OneNote?

Tags: webapp-rec

I use Google Docs for most of my document creation / management needs, but one thing I've found seriously lacking is a note / task management system along the lines of OneNote.

Does anything exist in the Google world which is suitable, or if not, then just generally on the web?

Comment: Maybe edit the title to reflect that you are aiming for a Google tool - might be more appropriate.

Comment: @tobeannounced: (meta comment: if you put "@" followed by the name, like I have done here, that user will get a notification. Example: @C.McAtackney )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Google Notebook](http://www.google.com/notebook/) and [Google Tasks](http://mail.google.com/tasks) <sup>[Help](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=106237)</sup> (in Gmail).

Comment: Upvoted - these are the tools that exist in the 'Google world' which are suitable.

Comment: Thanks neo - I totally forgot that Google Notebook existed. I clicked your link and it loaded up some notebooks that I had from three years ago. I guess I'll start using it again now.

Also, I wonder why it isn't linked to from the Gmail topbar? Sounds like a potential Greasemonkey script in the making.

Comment: From Google: "Google recently stopped development on Notebook, which means it's no longer open to sign-ups by new users or being improved."
Presumably that means the plug could be pulled any time on this useful tool.

Comment: @moioci per http://googlenotebookblog.blogspot.com/2009/01/stopping-development-on-google-notebook.html Google Notebook is still available for past users and won't be deleted. New users can't sign up anymore. You can also use Google Docs for notekeeping.

Comment: Google tasks is great for universal note capture if it's primarily text you're interested in. It has a very nice mobile view and also  slick Gmail and Gcal integration.

Answer (score 10):

http://www.evernote.com/ is definitely the most popular alternative.

Others worth mentioning are Springpad, and Simplenote (especially if you use an iPhone/iPad).

For task management, check out - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/online-to-do-list-apps

Comment: Thanks for the links - that "Remember the Milk" looks interesting, might give it a go. Cheers.

Comment: No worries - I would suggest having a look at Toodledo as well. Disclaimer: that is what I currently use.

Comment: When you do, have a look and see if you can add your thoughts here to help others http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4375/note-taking-apps-who-are-the-ideal-users-of-each-and-why-should-one-be-used-ove

Answer (score 1):

[Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) is a pretty solid note-taking web app (also has mobile versions and a desktop client).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Evernote - I've registered an account and will be giving it a go for a while to see how it compares to the Google Notebook answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free, web-based version of OneNote at http://www.onenote.com/

There's a free app for Windows (Metro and Desktop), Android, Mac, and iOS that will give you access to your OneNote Notebooks just about anywhere. The features do vary a little (can input handwriting and drawing in Metro, but not work offline - Android can work offline, but no drawing/handwriting), but various articles have featured team members talking about how they plan to improve feature parity.

At this point if you really want to use OneNote you can use it just about anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Recently came back to this question and thought it should be noted that Google Notebook is completely and utterly dead. Google Docs and Google Keep are the two alternatives Google is currently pointing people to.

[Google Docs](http://drive.google.com) is ok if you don't mind using a word processor for note taking. I'm reasonably certain it is an issue for you since you posted this question, but it might be fine for others.

[Google Keep](http://keep.google.com) is in many ways the successor to Google Notebook. I've been using it for the quick, one-off kind of notes while still using OneNote for meeting notes, class notes, and most of my other note taking.